# python how to mock a method?

Tags: python, mocking, patch

I want to test a http post method, this method will call some service, but the service cannot work in local test machine, so I want to mock it.

**test.py:**

```
@route(bp, '/count', methods=['POST'])
def count():
   from module import service
   ...
   total, ids = service(id, page, count) // total is a integer, ids is a list.
   ...
   return {'total': total, 'ids': ids}
```

**test case:**

```
@mock.patch("module.service")
def test_search_user(self, mock_service):
    mock_service.return_value=(1, [])

    url = url_for('users.count')
    params = { .... }

    response = self._test_app.post_json(
        url, params, headers=self.request_headers, expect_errors=True)

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

but test case is always failed, it tried to call `service` method, but it cannot work on my machine. I just want to mock it, but doesn't work.

Anyone can help me! Thanks in advance!

According to @syntonym answer, my test case should be wrote like this:

```
@mock.patch("test.service")
def test_search_user(self, mock_service):
    mock_service.return_value=(1, [])
```

Comment: So `service` in your first snippet should be replaced by a magickmock? Where does `service` come from? [Read this about where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)

Comment: look my update. I defined the `service` in a module.

Comment: patches work upon names, not on actual classes. So if you want that `service` in `testmodule` refers to the mock, you need to patch `@mock.patch("testmodule.service")`, not `module.service`. For more information read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

Comment: @syntonym yes, you are right, my patch() is wrong. thanks a lot! please post your answer,I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@mock.patch` actually takes the lookup name - not the place where the object you want to patch acutally resides. [The documentation reads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch):

> patch() works by (temporarily) changing the object that a name points to with another one. [...]
>   The basic principle is that you patch where an object is looked up,
>   which is not necessarily the same place as where it is defined.